# Show coloured log4j output in Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, log4j

How can I configure Log4j to show in red the dump of a

```
log.error("some error",exception)
```

if an uncaught exception occurs in my java code, eclipse would show it in red, but when I catch it and lo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Grep Console](http://marian.musgit.com/grepconsole/index.html) plugin which allows you to define styles for lines which match certain patterns. For example, error messages could be set to show up with a red background.